# How to hide from builtwith.com like websites?

Tags: script

Is it possible to be hiden from builtwith.com such websites (i.e) hide what type of ecommerce platform we are using.

Ref: http://builtwith.com/giftease.com

Thanks.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32023/how-to-hide-from-builtwith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuiltWith's methodology for determining which engine a site is using isn't public, but there are lots of "tells" that a site is running Magento:

- Your URL structure: http://www.yourdomain.com/checkout/cart/ is your cart's URL. You may want to consider making the URL something different.
- Your directory structure: /skin/frontend/ is included in the image paths.
- Your cookies: cookies start with "frontend"
- Your admin screen: Magento site admin screens are all located at http://www.yourdomain.com/admin and have a similar look and feel.

Source: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/top-5-clues-a-store-is-running-magento/

Comment: I suggest you change your admin URL anyways ^^